# Installing Arango Cluster on Gcloud

Tags: cluster-computing, gcloud, arangodb

I am trying to install an ArangoDB cluster on google cloud. I run the install script. At every try I run up against and issue with an SSH onto the server.  In the script there is an  SSH user "core" and the script is looking for a password for this user to do SSH onto the server to set it up. I have no idea what that could be and have searched everywhere.

I am running the script from my local machine using gcloud SDK.

Any thoughts welcome!

Comment: Can you share the code please?

Comment: Hi - I think i figured it out using https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance.  My ssh keys were messed up but i fixed using this link - I couldnt ssh on any instance from my local machine and now i can. Thanks!

Comment: I'm running into the same issue.  Can you provide more details on what was messed up and worked for you?  I'm working from a Ubuntu environment.